# i have a body.html file which i want to send as an email body as well as an attachment using sendmail or mail.how to do that?

Tags: bash, shell

i have a body.html file which i want to send as an email body as well as an attachment using sendmail or mail command only.body.html contains the body of the mail in html format. Recipients,subject and sender are all fixed.

Comment: So what? Did you read the *fine* manual? Did you tried something?

Comment: /bin/cat body.html | mail -a body.html -s "subject name || `/bin/date +'%d-%h-%y %H:%M'`" -r "`/bin/hostname`" recipient@example.com

Comment: I tried this one it sends the file(body.html) as attachment and the html file data as body but the mail body does not display it as a html mail rather a text mail only.

Comment: Search for ***multipart*** mail: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipurpose_Internet_Mail_Extensions